# "Pkgmgr is deprecated" error while installing Windows Media Player

Tags: windows-8.1, installation, windows-media-player, dism

While installing WMP or Sony PC Companion, the installation gives the same error that is:

> Note: The PkgMgr.exe has been deprecated. Please update your scripts to use dism.exe to extract, install, uninstall, configure and update features and packages for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Download this file to repair this problem: [Media Feature Pack for N and KN versions of Windows 8.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40744)

> The Media Feature Pack for N and KN versions of Windows 8.1 will
>   install Media Player and related technologies on a computer running
>   Windows 8.1 N or Windows 8.1 KN editions. For further information,
>   please see http://support.microsoft.com and query the Knowledge Base
>   for the article number KB2835517.

Comment: Can you add some more details - such as what program is at this link, and etc., so that this is a better and more fleshed out answer? Thanks!

Comment: this didnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

[PkgMgr.exe was added in Vista](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748979%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), but it is replaced by [DISM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh825236.aspx) since Windows 7 and now you get this message.

> DISM replaces the ImageX tool which was deprecated in Windows 8. DISM
>   also replaces Package Manager (Pkgmgr.exe), PEimg, and Intlcfg that
>   were included in previous deployment toolkits. DISM also adds new
>   functionality to improve the experience for offline servicing.

Post more details when you get this message.

Comment: I understand but could you share some light as to how to avoid this error.?

Comment: post more details. What are you doing? How do you install the WMP?

Comment: Well it all started when i started to connect my Xperia U to my Windows 8.1 PC and it did not get detected.Earlier no such problem had arrived but recently I had reformatted my system.
Now i thought that it might be some driver problem so i downloaded Sony's PC Companion which downloaded MTP drivers.During installation of those drivers this exact error arises leaving me unable to complete the procedure.

Comment: contact Sony so that they can change their setup

Answer (score 0):

Use these two commands with administrative privilege::

```
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature  /All /FeatureName:MediaPlayback /NoRestart
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature  /All /FeatureName:WindowsMediaPlayer /NoRestart
```

This will enable/install Windows media player feature. Or you may install Media Player in Optional Feature app. Run **OptionalFeatures.exe** & check **Media Features**.

[image: Media Player Feature]